# How to send a python-cgi variable back to my javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, cgi

I have a python cgi script that produces a variable that I want to send back over to my javascript file. This is the following variable, and it exists in the file get_animals.py:

```
data = ["Dog", "Cat", "Frog"]
```

I have already tried using jquery to get this data, but I am not really sure if I went about it the right way.

The following code is in my javascript file that is trying to fetch the list of animals:

```
    $.get( "./cgi-bin/get_animals.py", function( data ) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

However, the console does not log anything. Is this the correct way to retrieve data from a cgi script?

Comment: When troubleshooting with jQuery AJAX, you should definitely be using the `$.get([url]).done([function to be executed on success]).fail([*function to be executed on failure*])` syntax to catch errors.
Your current code only returns the response from a *successful* request.

Comment: You need to encode the python into a JSON string, and print that into the body of the response.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Ok, I I encoded it into a json string in the following way
`print("Content-Type: application/json\n\n")
print(json.dumps(data))`, but now data is just an empty array according to the console log.